# Inetpub folder creation

Tags: asp.net, iis

Out of thought does the `inetpub` folder get created upon enabling IIS through turning on Windows features. Because I have enabled this IIS feature and did not notice this folder.

Comment: It depends on which IIS feature you enabled, and also your Windows version/edition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `inetpub` folder depends on enabling IIS through turning on Windows features. This folder get created when you enable the IIS through turning on windows features.

Comment: Which windows features are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

May I know how did you install IIS?
This is the link about how to install IIS step by step in windows server and windows client:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-85/installing-iis-85-on-windows-server-2012-r2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7

You could open IIS manager and check whether Default Website is always being placed In inetpub\wwwroot. So if the site exist, then you should be able to find the inetpub folder.

If the folder is not created for some reason, please try to reinstall IIS via turn windows features on or off or "Add role and feature".

Answer (score 0):

If the inetpub folder exists but does not contain wwwroot, then it is possible that IIS is enabled but the ASP.NET 4.8 feature is not. Install it using Turn Windows Features On or Off.

[image]